# why does my clustered index scan have ordered = false

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I look to at my query plan, I see plenty of clustered index seeks (yay!) and scans (not quite so yay!) but in some of them ordered = False.  I will mention that we have parallelism involved, though it does not appear to have any relation to these.  The indexes were set up with ordering.

What does this mean?  That the query plan is ignoring this order?  Or that the query is choosing not to order?  Or... heck, I have no idea what I'm looking at...!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It just means that the query optimiser doesn't require an explicit order guarantee either for some later operator in the plan (e.g. merge join or stream aggregate) or to avoid a sort because you have explicitly requested an `order by`.

When `ordered = false` you might in some circumstances get an [allocation ordered scan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlserverstorageengine/when-can-allocation-order-scans-be-used) rather than a scan that follows the linked list of the leaf pages in index key order for example.

Comment: Since the scan type: index order or allocation order does not appear in the execution plan or elsewhere, what to tell people with questions such as this one? Basically, one can trade scan speed for data safety, no? I guess I would say, maybe consider forcing allocation order scans when doing big scans on tables, which are not changing at the time of the scan...thinking DWs. Thoughts?

Comment: @ooutwire - In a DW if the table is on a read only file group wonder if you might get an allocation ordered scan considered automatically without having to use `nolock` or `tablock`. Would make sense but haven't tested this.

Comment: I agree, but the DWs I use are never read-only (unless we are mucking with them surreptitiously). I suppose if little logical fragmentation exists in the first place and nothing is going on to cause page splits, then one may see little gain from forcing the allocation scan. Guess it'll make a good blog post. I have some TB-sized DWs I can attack for fun.

Comment: Makes good sense, Martin.  Excellent link you shared as well.  Thanks much!

Answer (score 4):

I believe the `Ordered` portion of an index scan is just indicative of whether or not your query is ordered by the index key column(s).

Say you have something like this:

```
-- Table Definition for reference
CREATE TABLE [HumanResources].[Employee](
    [EmployeeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NationalIDNumber] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [ContactID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LoginID] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [ManagerID] [int] NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [BirthDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [MaritalStatus] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [Gender] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [HireDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SalariedFlag] [dbo].[Flag] NOT NULL,
    [VacationHours] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [SickLeaveHours] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [CurrentFlag] [dbo].[Flag] NOT NULL,
    [rowguid] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee_EmployeeID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO



use AdventureWorks
go

select *
from HumanResources.Employee
```

This would be a clustered index scan with `Ordered = False`.  But modify it to look like this:

```
use AdventureWorks
go

select *
from HumanResources.Employee
order by EmployeeID
```

You will then have `Ordered = True` because you are ordering by the index key column.

But if you have something like this (`ORDER BY` on a non-key column):

```
use AdventureWorks
go

select *
from HumanResources.Employee
order by ContactID
```

Then `Ordered = False` because the sorting isn't based on the index key column(s).

Answer (score 0):

A problem (and solution) I just hit regarding `Ordered = False`:

I had the following operators in my Execution Plan:

- a **Sort**, spilling to tempdb with 1.7 GB of data, which got its data from
- a **Compute Scalar**, a bunch of columns getting Explicit (but also Implicit!) conversions
- ...which came from what should have been an `Ordered = True` **Clustered Index Scan**.

My Clustered Index scan was getting the `Ordered = False` treatment, because one of the implicit conversions was for one of the Index's Key Columns!

Once the implicit conversion on that key column was remedied, the plan changed to a much faster:

- Compute Scalar, columns getting Explicit and Implicit conversions, but not the Clustered Index Key Columns!
- Clustered Index Scan with Ordered = True

This avoided the Sort and the spill to TempDB completely!